# Escaping a double-quote in inline c# script within javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, escaping

I need to escape a double quote in inline c# within javascript. Code is below:

```
if ("<%= TempData["Message"]%>" == "") {
    // code
};
```

Normally, I would just use single quotes like so:

```
if ('<%= TempData["Message"]%>' == "") {
    // code
};
```

However, `TempData["Message"]` has single quotes within it (when it contains a link generated by the Html.ActionLink() helper in ASP.NET MVC). So while I could change all the ActionLink helpers inside `TempData["Message"]` to  tags, it's an interesting problem and would been keen to hear if anyone has an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx).
This method is new to ASP.Net 4.0; for earlier versions, use the [WPL](http://wpl.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Hmm, I don't have .NET 4. What does it do?

Comment: It escapes a bunch of characters.  Use WPL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [AjaxHelper.JavaScriptStringEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxhelper.javascriptstringencode.aspx) method inside a Razor view, like this:

```
if ("@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(TempData["Message"].ToString())" == "") {
    // do stuff
}
```

If that's too verbose, create this little helper in `/App_Code/JS.cshtml`

```
@helper Encode(string value) {
    @(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(value))
}
```

Which you can then call from any view:

```
@JS.Encode("'single these quotes are encoded'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have addressed this by writing a HtmlHelper that encodes the strings to a format acceptable in Javascript:

```
public static string JSEncode(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string source)
{
    return (source ?? "").Replace(@"'", @"\'").Replace(@"""", @"\""").Replace(@"&", @"\&").Replace(((char)10).ToString(), "<br />");
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
if ('<%= Html.JSEncode( TempData["Message"] ) %>' == "") {
    // code
};
```

Comment: That's very wrong.  You should not be replacing `\r` with `<br />` tags, and there are more characters that you need to escape.

Comment: Specifically: backslash itself (otherwise `\"` is escaped to `\\"` and breaks the string with security implications) and other newline characters.

Comment: This is what works for me, and the messages I need to encode.  Feel free to adjust to your individual needs