# C# Model string with newlines to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model passed into a cshtml view, and I'm trying to create a variable with a string from the model. The problem is that the string contains newlines, and when I create the variable, the newlines are not converted, and I end up with an `Unterminated string constant` error in the Javascript.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
var something = @Model.string;
```

How can I pass the model attribute so that new lines are preserved in the javascript variable?

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765122/escaping-a-double-quote-in-inline-c-sharp-script-within-javascript

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756829/pass-c-sharp-model-from-view-to-javascript

Comment: you could try: Html.Raw(Model.string) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449782/how-to-create-a-javascript-string-in-razor

Comment: I'm finding these with [this search](/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bjs%5D+%5Brazor%5D+pass+string+to+javascript). Remember it's important to search thoroughly before posting, not least because the answer is probably already here somewhere.

Comment: @ReintJanHoiting: Part of that is probably missing, see the second link above.

Comment: BTW, unless your using some sort of csjs, I would suggest using data-* attributes in CSHTML. This allows you to create a pattern that seperates the data from the code - e.g. `<div style="display:none" data-something="@Json.Encode(Model.String)"></div>` with JS `$('[data-something').data('something')`

Comment: @ReintJanHoiting Using a `Html.Raw()` method isn't save (beause of XSS possibility attack). Just use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` method.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you:

```
var something = @:Model.ToString();
```